# Laravel validation - unique with nullable where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have to write validation rule that should verify if `address` is unique on rows where `routing_id` has given value. That is simple. But in some cases `routing_id` field may be `NULL` and then my validation request rule doesn't work.

Here is my rule:

```
$rules['address']   = 'required|ip|unique:vias,address'.\Route::current()->getParameter('via')->id.',id,routing_id,'.request()->input('routing_id'));
```

When I am patching row with `null` as `routing_id` in my `POST` array I want my `address` to be unique within all rows with nulled `routing_id` field. But it does not work.

And my question is: how to solve it?

Comment: Why did you concat this: `address'.\Route::current()->getParameter('via')->id.'` secondly are you using L5.4?

Comment: unique rule needs:  table (`vias`), column (`address`), id to be ignored when patching ( `\Route::current()->getParameter('via')->id`), name of id column (`id`) and then additional where conditions: so i have: where `routing_id` equals given `routing_id` post value. (project has been built using L5.3 and I didn't update it to 5.4 yet)

Comment: Remember: unique:table,column,except,idColumn
In that case should look this way:
`$routing_id = \Route::current()->getParameter('via')->id;
"required|ip|unique:vias,address,{$routing_id},routing_id"`

Comment: You dont get it. `routing_id` IS NOT my `id` column. I need to have unique `address` value where `routing_id` is null or have any other value. It works properly when `routing_id` has any value other than NULL.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours of research I finally found where the problem was.

By using `Store Request Validation` implemented in Laravel I can modify POSTed parameters. In my validation rule posted above I had

```
request()->input('routing_id')
```

which was retrieving **FRESH** copy of request params, not these modified by me. That is why my `NULL` values wasn't used - cause I was conditionally merging some special values with `NULL` value.

Params was properly changed, but only inside `StoreRequestValidation` class.

Answer (score 0):

you can first check if address!=null then 
do validate 
like these code

```
$this->validate($request,
            [
                'name' => 'required|max:50',
                'lastname' => 'required|max:50',
                'city_id' => 'required',
                'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg'
            ]);

        if(isset($request->address))
        {
            $this->validate($request,
                [
                    'address' => 'required|max:150|email|unique:users'
                ]);
        }
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer, include an explanation how and why this solves the problem.